# Mandelbrot Lockbits

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement Lockbits for my Mandelbrot renderer because it is better performance wise. However, I seem to get a very interesting result when trying to render the mandelbrot function. What I do basically is get the rgb values for every pixel and then putting them in the bytes array. After that, I copy them all to the bitmap and draw them.

code for the renderer:

```
private void Draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    double minX = centerX - zoom / 2, minY = centerY - zoom / 2;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int ret = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2000000];
    for (int x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < pictureBox1.Height; y++)
        {
            double a = minX + (double)x / pictureBox1.Width * zoom;
            double b = minY + (double)y / pictureBox1.Height * zoom;
            Complex c = new Complex(a, b);
            Complex z = new Complex(0, 0);
            int it = 0;
            do
            {
                it++;
                z.Square();
                z.Add(c);
                if (z.Magnitude() > 2.0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (it < 50);
            int r = (it % 32) * 7;
            int g = (it % 16) * 14;
            int b = (it % 128) * 2;
            int l = 255;
            if (ret <= 1999997)
            {
                bytes[ret] = (byte)g;
                bytes[ret + 1] = (byte)b;
                bytes[ret + 2] = (byte)r;
                ret = ret + 3;
            }
        }
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, 2000000);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Wrong byte order, RGB == blue at offset 0, green at 1, red at 2.  And you can't ignore stride at 24bpp.  Strongly favor 32bpp since that matches the screen, stride is no longer relevant and a pixel is simply an int instead of 3 bytes.

Comment: I'd use a 2D array of Ks and access it in a  parallel loop. In a timer you can create images to show a progress animation, which will be fast compared to the calculations..

Comment: Mind to explain a bit more?

Comment: @TaW What do the Ks represent?

Comment: The results of the computations for each point, ie the number of iterations needed to leave the chosen radius. Or the limit kMax.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things go wrong here. To make the example work, I declared some variables inside the method. Next time, please provide a reproducible example, so that people don't have to fiddle around that much.

I also changed the `Complex` type to `System.Numerics.Complex` because you didn't mention which library you are using.

1. You are creating a bitmap without specifying the pixel format [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thev4.png)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_). Doing so will use 32 Bits per pixel. You either need to stick to that format or specify the format to use. Using 32 bit could actually be beneficial, because CPUs can deal with 32 bits quite well. Anyway, I'll go with 24 bits here, since your code is written that way and for another reason.

   ```
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
   ```
2. `b` was declared twice, so the code did not compile. I changed the latter one to `blue`.
3. If you have a 24 bit Bitmap, the end of the bitmap might not align well for processing rows and columns. To account for that alignment, you have to consider the [Stride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride?view=net-5.0). The stride adds some bytes at the end of each row so that the next row starts at a multiple of 4 or 8 (don't know exactly).

   That means: after each line, you must add that difference to your `ret` variable:

   ```
   ret = ret + bmpData.Stride - pictureBox1.Width * 3;
   ```
4. Now that this is done, your outer loop is X and your inner loop is Y, but the stride needs to be considered for rows, not columns. So, flip the loops:

   ```
   for (int y = 0; y < pictureBox1.Height; y++)
   {
       for (int x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Width; x++)
       {
   ```
5. Also, your byte array always has a size of 2.000.000 bytes. If the picture box requires less pixels, you're attempting to copy more pixels into the bitmap that available. This results in an access violation.

   Fix that by allocating a `byte[]` of exactly the size you need.

   ```
   byte[] bytes = new byte[bmp.Height * bmpData.Stride];
   ```

   Then change all boundary checks as well.
6. Hans Passant mentions in the comments, your colors are in wrong order. Should be

   ```
   bytes[ret] = (byte)blue;
   bytes[ret + 1] = (byte)g;
   bytes[ret + 2] = (byte)r;
   ```

I didn't want to post the full code, because I think you made a lot of mistakes and should fix them yourself. Copy/paste is not good for learning. But, here's the result when fixed when running with parameters

```
var zoom = 2.0;
var centerX = -.2;
var centerY = 0.0;
```

[image: Mandelbrot]

You'll notice that the image looks stretched if it's not square. You  might want to compensate that in your calculations.

Also: you currently draw the image within the Paint event. Your window might be painted more often than you think. Perhaps you find a better place.

On my machine, a full screen update takes ~2100ms for 2560x1440 pixels. It could still need a bit more performance :-)
It's possible to use `Parallel.For()` on the outer y-Loop if you avoid using `ret` and replace it by a calculation instead. That way I get it under 300 ms (8 cores; 16 threads).

Comment: Minor performance improvements: switching to 32 bit color. Using a 32 bit `int` instead of accessing 3 individual bytes. Calculating `b` outside the x-loop. Gets me closer to 200ms.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'm sorry that I didn't notice that b was declared twice, I had changed the variable on SO for logical purposes, however it was declared as something else in my IDE.

Comment: @SuchJitter: no problem. It was fun working on fractals.

Comment: May I ask something? at this `ret = ret + bmpData.Stride - pictureBox1.Width * 3;`, why do you multiply the width with 3? Also, how did you determine when the line ends?